# Angular, Express.js - Route is called twice

Tags: node.js, angular, express

Note: I simplified the code for testing.

I have an express.js route with the following code:

```
// /auth/register/confirm/:confirmationToken

const registerConfirm = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('registerConfirm');
  res.status(httpStatus.OK).json({ msg: 'Registration confirmed' });
});
```

I call it from Angular with the following code:

```
this.authService.registerConfirm('abcdef').subscribe();
```

In my node.js console, I always get two lines with `registerConfirm` instead of one:

```
registerConfirm
registerConfirm
```

It's as if it was making two `PUT` requests from Angular except that in my network's tab I only have one `OPTION` and one `PUT` call. For a console.log it's not an issue but when I have code that does database operations it is called twice and messes everything.

I also tried to call this route from Postman and it worked properly. It doesn't work when the call is made from Angular.

Comment: Could you show the part where you assign the handler to a particular route in express?

Comment: @Shlang I'm not sure what you mean, but here is where I declare the route as a PUT request:

```
import express from 'express';

import { registerConfirm } from '../controllers/auth.controller.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.put('/register/confirm/:confirmationToken', registerConfirm);

export default router;
```

Comment: @Shlang This is an issue coming from Angular. I just tried to create a new project with only the API call and I get the same issue

Comment: It is not an "issue" it is [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), not sure why your controller gets called on `OPTIONS` tho.

Comment: options/preflight is unlikely calling express put handler. it could be that you're calling http client twice when subscribing or similar. so, you should include both component and service method

Comment: @Shlang I removed CORS to test and you are right I don't have a duplicate request anymore